# How to select sum or 0 if no records exist?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

```
using (AdviserReserveEntities Adv=new AdviserReserveEntities())
{
   decimal sum= Adv.Credits.Where(u => u.UserIdRef == 2).Sum(a => a.Amount);
}
```

if no record founds following exception is occurred:

> The cast to value type 'Int64' failed because the materialized value
>   is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the q`uery must
>   use a nullable type.

how to return 0 if no record founds?

Comment: Can you post the entity class? you code works fine for me. Returns 0 sucessful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use a nullable type:

```
decimal? sum = Adv.Credits
                  .Where(u => u.UserIdRef == 2)
                  .Sum(a => (decimal?)a.Amount);
```

Watch the cast in the sum expression. This way you will get null back when there was no element. You can add the coalesce operator to get a default value:

```
decimal sum = Adv.Credits
                 .Where(u => u.UserIdRef == 2)
                 .Sum(a => (decimal?)a.Amount)
              ?? 0;
```

The solution mentioned by Raphael and Justin is worse, because first checking with Any() will cause in **two** database queries instead of just one.

Comment: Isn't MSDN saying that sum returns zero if source contains no elements? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var records = Adv.Credits.Where(u => u.UserIdRef == 2);
decimal sum = records.Any() ? records.Sum(a => a.Amount) : 0m;
```